# React router replace() function appends '[Object%20object]' to url instead of re-routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've been working through react-router's [auth-flow example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js) and I'm having trouble with the `replace()` function. I'll call `this.context.router.replace('/')` at my route `'/app/'`, but instead of rerouting me to `'/'`, it reroutes me to `'/app/[object%20Object]'`.

I already added `contextTypes: { router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired }` to the component, so that isn't the problem.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. You figure this out?

Comment: @Banjer yeah I finally figured out that `this` in `this.context.router.replace` wasn't bound to the correct object. After some refactoring, I ended up creating [this very simple example](https://github.com/geezhawk/django-react-auth/tree/master/assets/js) of react-router authentication. I hope it's a little clearer than the official example. I also wrote [a tutorial](http://geezhawk.github.io/2016/03/24/user-authentication-with-react-and-django-rest-framework.html) for using react-router with Django Rest Framework. Hope that helps, and sorry about forgetting to write my answer here.